# How to make a form toolbar docked at the bottom of the screen in ExtJS6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a tall form panel, how can I make the bottom toolbar with the submit button floating at a fixed position at the bottom of the screen?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.myobj.MyPanel', {
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [
            {fieldLabel: 'Field'},
            {fieldLabel: 'Field'},
        ],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            ui: 'footer',
            fixed: true,
            items: [
                {xtype: 'button', text: 'Submit', formBind: true}
            ]
        }]    
    }],

});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12ai)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need the parent to have a layout defined (so it has an height), and use [`scrollable`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-scrollable).

For example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12ap